# How to restrict only few pages accessible on mobile device instead of whole SharePoint functionality?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, browser-compatibility, mobile

How to restrict only few pages accessible on mobile device instead of whole SharePoint functionality?

I have few pages in SharePoint 2013,I have mobile compatability view for visiting the pages.

But I want to restrict some  pages for user viewing from mobile/iPad.

Is there any method is there to restrict that???

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box there is no settings to handle this requirement. One possible solution is to add JavaScript to pages and check the user agent string to identify the device and probably redirect to Access Denied page.

This solution is not fool proof.

Comment: Is there any sample JavaScript available?? Canu shre the sample exaample url..